# Google maps V3 API - css reset causes scrollbars

Tags: css, maps, reset, css-reset

This is in my reset script:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

My google code sizes the infowindow to fit the content unless I have this code in my CSS. By trial and error I found that if I remove margin:0 then the scrollbars disappear and the content fits correctly, and the infowindow is resized as expected.

I also found that if I removed the "p," from the list of tags it works as well - so I am assuming I can't have the margin set to 0 in my reset script.

I have no idea how to resolve this. It makes no sense!

This code actually works and the google maps infowindow is fine:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
p{
 padding: 0;
 border: 0;
 outline: 0;
 font-weight: inherit;
 font-style: inherit;
 font-size: 100%;
 font-family: inherit;
 vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How are you including the Google Maps in your web page? Is it a popup window? An iframe? Or is it embedded directly into one of pages, like contactus.html? Without knowing how the HTML works its hard to pinpoint errors. Additionally, does this only happen in IE, or does it happen in multiple browsers? Knowing the scope helps determine if its a browser issue or a coding issue.

If it is possible, my solution would be to use a different stylesheet for the web page with Google Maps. That way you don't have to deal with whatever the issue is in the reset.css file.

Comment: The code is a DIV on the page, i.e. <div id="map"></div>. The map is put in place via script, i.e.
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-16.43,136.09);
    var myOptions = {
  zoom: 2,
  center: latlng,
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),myOptions);

Pretty basic stuff.

At the moment I just modified the reset script globally, since the only thing changed in it is the margin on the <p> tags.